# Exception when creating an activity: Could not select item Parcel unable to marshal value

Tags: android, android-manifest, listactivity

I am trying to call an Activity from another instance of the activity. The code is supposed to be a simple file browser (part of a larger application). I am using a ListActivity, and when an item (such as a folder) is selected, it is supposed to open it up in the new Activity. I have a feeling it is a problem with the AndroidManifest (which just has the basic  tag). Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. The Object I am passing to the next Activity must implement either the Serializable interface or the Parcellable interface.